# Swift: set Image to Custom cell ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

i want to set the Image to Custom cell. I am confuse how to do this.
lets say I have a custom cell in my UITable View.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(imageTapped(img:)))
    cell.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    return cell
}
```

Now as soon as i tap in the Image  the following function gets called:

```
func imageTapped(img: AnyObject){
    print("Image clicked.")

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)
        print(image)
        //i am uploading the photo from here. and i want to set this  picture to my cell imageView.
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil
}
```

I am confused how to call the cell imageview from here??
How can i further procced?? I just need to set That obtained image to imgeView in cell other everything works fine..

Comment: The code you have added is probably inside the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` not inside your tapgesture method.

Comment: everything works fine upto here. I can select the image but did not get the point how to set in cell imageview

Comment: everything works fine upto here. I can select the image but did not get the point how to set in cell imageview.. yes it is inside that..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I have just tested

I have a custom TableViewCell, named `ImageTableViewCell`, which contains a single UIImageView, named `customImageView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellImage", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

    // initialising with some dummy data of mine
    cell.customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image\(indexPath.row).png")

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(_:)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return cell
}
```

and then in the ViewController

```
func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let myCell = sender.view as! ImageTableViewCell
    myCell.customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageTapped.jpg")
}
```

This should update the image immediately, without any requirement to reload the table